# how can i display my admin panel question in static java script

Tags: django, django-admin

this is my js file in static folder:

```
let questions = [
    {
        question :"my question",
     
        choiceA : "Correct",
        choiceB : "Wrong",
        choiceC : "Wrong",
        correct : "B"
    }
```

this is admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

this is model.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

views.py

```
def quiz(request):
    question=Question.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{"question":question})
```

this question is what should be written in js file for the place of "my question"?

Comment: So, you have a JS file in static, and a view to display all of the questions in database. You want to store the questions in JS array.  Right?

Comment: yes faizan thats exacty what i want

Comment: hum.. One way to do this is, loop over the objects and construct a JS array. 
Here is what I am thinking:
The static files are loaded in **index.html** which makes the **questions** variable in JS file available. You can loop over the question object and construct a JS array.

Makes sense?

Comment: can you please code it for me...

Answer (score 1):

In **index.html**

```
    <script>
   {% for question in questions %}
        let question = {}
        question["name"] = problem.name
        questions.push(question)
   {% endfor %}
</script>
```

In **views.py**, just to increase readability change

```
{"question": question} to {"questions": question}
```

Notice the "s" in "question". This improve readability in the for loop